# E-commerce package for PHP / Customer management and "order tracking"

Tags: php, tracking, shopping-cart

We're developing a PHP based website through which people can subscribe to certain services. I'm looking for a solution (open-source or reasonably priced) that helps track customer's orders - what have they ordered --> have they paid or not --> has that been approved by the site administrator, etc. The end-user can have multiple subscriptions, so a mechanism must be available for him to see those details himself (ie, invoices, etc).

If the user cancels an order or wishes that his subscription should not be renewed, the package should allow those changes to be made.

Of course, these details should be easily accessible by our software to determine whether to give login access to the user or not, so the data should ideally be stored in MySQL tables.

I'm not looking for a shopping-cart system, but more of an "order-tracking system".

Any suggestions? I'm not sure if Zen-Cart or Magento will do the above - anyone have any experience of the same?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at osCommerce.  It's a PHP-based e-commerce that sounds like it can handle what you want.  It doesn't look like it has inventory management but it sounds like you don't need it.

I don't have any experience with it so I can't go into any more detail, sorry.

The features list is here:   [osCommerce Docs](http://www.oscommerce.com/solutions/oscommerce)